# VBA do loop issue

Tags: vba, loops, userform

I am trying to finish a school project. It is using a Userform and asking for inputs to create a sandwich. My problem is I cannot get a variable to go up by one after the loop has been done once. 
Every time the user enters a sub, I want the userform to go back to empty, and their selections to be entered on the excel sheet. This is what I have so far

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
Dim m As Integer

m = 1

    Do

        Select Case True

            Case optBreadRye.Value
                Range("C2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(6)
                Range("D2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)
                Range("E2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)

            Case optBreadWheat.Value
                Range("D2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(5)
                Range("C2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)
                Range("E2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)

            Case optBreadWhite.Value
               Range("E2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(4)
               Range("C2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)
               Range("D2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)

        End Select

        If chkRoastBeef = True Then
             Range("F2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0.5)
                ElseIf chkRoastBeef = False Then
                    Range("F2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)
        End If

        If chkChickenBreast = True Then
             Range("G2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0.5)
                ElseIf chkChickenBreast = False Then
                    Range("G2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)
        End If

        If chkTurkeyBreast = True Then
             Range("H2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0.5)
                ElseIf chkTurkeyBreast = False Then
                    Range("h2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)
        End If

        If chkHam = True Then
             Range("I2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0.5)
                ElseIf chkHam = False Then
                    Range("I2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)
        End If

        If chkCheese = True Then
             Range("J2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0.5)
                ElseIf chkCheese = False Then
                    Range("j2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)
        End If

        If chkVeggie = True Then
             Range("K2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0.5)
                ElseIf chkVeggie = False Then
                    Range("k2").Offset(m, 0).Value = FormatCurrency(0)
        End If

      Range("l2").Offset(m, 0).Value = lblPrice.Caption

    With frmOrder
        .chkCheese.Value = False
        .chkChickenBreast.Value = False
        .chkHam.Value = False
        .chkRoastBeef.Value = False
        .chkTurkeyBreast.Value = False
        .chkVeggie.Value = False
        .optBreadRye.Value = False
        .optBreadWheat.Value = False
        .optBreadWhite.Value = False
        .lblPrice.Caption = Format(0, "$0.00")

    End With


m = m + 1
Exit Do
Loop

End Sub
```

I know this is not the best formatting or most efficient way to do this, but my professor is not a help by any means. I have been learning everything by our class book and google.

I just cant get m to go up by one every time. I think it has to do with the placement of the "Exit Do" "Loop" or "m = m + 1"

The form:

[image: Form]

The worksheet:

[image: Excel sheet]

Comment: I believe it's going up by 1, but with the Exit right after that, your loop only runs 1 time?  Are you getting an error before `m = m + 1` and I would put the Exit Do, only in a place where the loop should end prematurely, if that makes sense?

Comment: I am not getting an error - the first press of "Add" works fine. But when I enter the second one, it just writes that over top the first one - that is why I think the variable m is not being risen (because if theory the Offset would make it go down a row.) I have the Exit Do there because I was having trouble with infinite loops when it is not.
Thanks for telling me about Rubberduck, I will definitely check it out.

Comment: you m variable needs to be global if you want it to increment on each press of the addition button. Look up scope of variables as m currently only resides in the sub so each press of the button it is reset.

Comment: Where is that code written in? How does the form get displayed?

Comment: I tried making the variable m public, but it didn't change. Sorry, I forgot to include the subs name. it is written within the Userform, which is shown by a main module attached to the button order.

Comment: @alexredskisn96  when you made it public did you still set it to 1 in the Private Sub btnAdd_Click()?

Comment: @alexredskisn96 thanks for the checkmark - please make sure you ask if you have any question about it: it's more important that you fully understand what's going on than *this program* works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the spreadsheet is none of the form's concern. The job of a form is to *collect user input*, period.

Your loop has no exit condition, and unconditionally exits at the end of the first iteration: it's useless, remove it.

You need a way for the form to tell its caller "hey, I have new data for you". The best way to do this is with an event:

```
Public Event NewOrderLine(ByVal bread As BreadType, ByVal contents As Stuffing)
```

...and enums:

```
Public Enum BreadType
    BreadType_None
    BreadType_Rye
    BreadType_Wheat
    BreadType_White
End Enum

Public Enum Stuffing
    Stuffing_None = 0
    Stuffing_RoastBeef = 2 ^ 0
    Stuffing_ChickenBreast = 2 ^ 1
    Stuffing_TurkeyBreast = 2 ^ 2
    Stuffing_Ham = 2 ^ 3
    Stuffing_Cheese = 2 ^ 4
    Stuffing_Veggie = 2 ^ 5
End Enum
```

Now when the form's [Add] button is clicked, it ran *raise the event* and pass the parameters to the caller:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click()

    Dim bread As BreadType
    bread = SelectedBreadType

    Dim contents As Stuffing
    contents = SelectedStuffings

    RaiseEvent NewOrderLine(bread, contents)
    ClearFormFields

End Sub

Private Property Get SelectedBreadType() As BreadType
    Select Case True
        Case optBreadRye.Value
            SelectedBreadType = BreadType_Rye
        Case optBreadWheat.Value
            SelectedBreadType = BreadType_Wheat
        Case optBreadWhite.Value
            SelectedBreadType = BreadType_White
        Case Else
            SelectedBreadType = BreadType_None
    End Select
End Property

Private Property Get SelectedStuffings() As Stuffing
    Dim result As Stuffing
    If chkRoastBeef.Value Then result = result + Stuffing_RoastBeef
    If chkChickenBreast.Value Then result = result + Stuffing_ChickenBreast
    If chkTurkeyBreast.Value Then result = result + Stuffing_TurkeyBreast
    If chkHam.Value Then result = result + Stuffing_Ham
    If chkCheese.Value Then result = result + Stuffing_Cheese
    If chkVeggie.Value Then result = result + Stuffing_Veggie
    SelectedStuffings = result
End Property
```

Note that the `Stuffing` values are cumulative; their underlying values are powers of 2. This is known as a *flag enum*, because it works like a bit mask: you use bitwise logic to determine whether a "flag" is included in the value:

```
Private Function HasFlag(ByVal value As Long, ByVal flag As Long) As Boolean
    HasFlag = (value And flag) = flag
End Function
```

So back on the worksheet's code-behind, you can do this:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents orderForm As frmOrder
Private currentOrderLine As Long
```

And handle the `NewOrderLine` event:

```
Private Sub orderForm_NewOrderLine(ByVal bread As BreadType, ByVal contents As Stuffing)
    'update the worksheet at currentOrderLine accordingly
End Sub
```

The [Order] button would be responsible for assigning the `orderForm` object reference:

```
Private Sub OrderButton_Click()
    Set orderForm = New frmOrder
    orderForm.Show
End Sub
```

---

I'd make a standard procedural module dedicated to computing the prices:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetBreadPrice(ByVal bread As BreadType)
    'you figure that out
End Function

Public Function GetContentsPrice(ByVal contents As Stuffing)
    'you figure that out
End Function
```

And then the form could call these functions to "preview" the price of the order, and the worksheet could call these functions to compute the actual total order amount. Say the module is called `Prices`:

```
Private Sub UpdatePriceLabel()
    breadPrice = Prices.GetBreadPrice(bread)
    contentsPrice = Prices.GetContentsPrice(contents)
    totalPrice = breadPrice + contentsPrice
    lblPrice.Caption = Format(totalPrice, "$0.00")
End Sub
```